# query with columns of same an different tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables with structure as shown below:

```
THINGS
COLUMNA            COLUMNB
Fruits             Apple
Fruits             Pear
Fruits             Grapes
Dairy products     Yoghurt
.......

QUANTITY
COLUMNC         COLUMND
Fruits           1
Apple            2
Pear             3
Yoghurt          1
Dairy products   1
```

I need a query to get something like:

COLUMA AND COLUMN C of these way:

```
RESULTA         RESULTB
Fruits          1,2,3
Dairy Products  1
```

The query SQL that I try is:

```
select COLUMNA, listagg(COLUMND,',') within group (order by COLUMND) from THINGS, QUANTITY  where COLUMNA=COLUMNC group by COLUMNC;
```

Is this possible? I have tried to get this but to no avail. I am working on Oracle 12.

Comment: Could you add the query you tried?

Comment: Is hard to me. Because privacy I've adapted the table names. Something like that: select COLUMNA, listagg(COLUMND,',') within group (order by COLUMND) from THINGS, QUANTITY  where COLUMNA=COLUMNC group by COLUMNC;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not quite clear how do you join data, but for given examples this works:

```
select columna result, listagg(columnd, ', ') within group (order by columnd) resultb
  from (select distinct columna, columnd 
          from things t 
          join quantity q on q.columnc in (t.columna, t.columnb))
  group by columna
```

Test:

```
with things(columna, columnb) as (
    select 'Fruits',         'Apple'   from dual union all
    select 'Fruits',         'Pear'    from dual union all
    select 'Fruits',         'Grapes'  from dual union all
    select 'Dairy products', 'Yoghurt' from dual ),
quantity(columnc, columnd) as (
    select 'Fruits',          1 from dual union all 
    select 'Apple',           2 from dual union all 
    select 'Pear',            3 from dual union all 
    select 'Yoghurt',         1 from dual union all 
    select 'Dairy products',  1 from dual )
select columna result, listagg(columnd, ', ') within group (order by columnd) resultb
  from (select distinct columna, columnd 
          from things t join quantity q on q.columnc in (t.columna, t.columnb))
  group by columna
```

Result:

```
RESULT         RESULTB
-------------- ----------
Dairy products 1
Fruits         1, 2, 3
```

Comment: not works for me, not shows all info. Could I put an real example with real tables to check it?

Comment: Please provide such examples (fruits are OK) so we have chance to verify condition for `join` and please explain logic. `Listagg` is only the last step after proper join.

Comment: It works!!! I try to make the query during tree days!! Only one question, the join statement is is like where q.columcc=t.columna and qcolumnc=t.columna???